# Non-left-recursive PEG grammar for an "expression"

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, programming-languages, lexer

It's either a simple identifier (like `cow`) something surrounded by brackets (`(...)`) something that looks like a method call (`...(...)`) or something that looks like a member access (`thing.member`):

```
def expr = identifier | 
           "(" ~> expr <~ ")" | 
           expr ~ ("(" ~> expr <~ ")") | 
           expr ~ "." ~ identifier
```

It's given in Scala Parser Combinator syntax, but it should be pretty straightforward to understand. It's similar to how expressions end up looking in many programming languages (hence the name `expr`) However, as it stands, it is left-recursive and causes my nice PEG parser to explode.

I have not succeeded in factoring out the left-recursion while still maintaining correctness for cases like `(cow.head).moo(dog.run(fast))`. How can I refactor this, or would I need to shift to some parser-generator that can tolerate left recursive grammars?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The trick is to have multiple rules where the first element of each rule is the next rule instead of being a recursive call to the same rule, and the rest of the rule is optional and repeating. For example the following would work for your example:

```scala
def expr              = method_call
def method_call       = member_access ~ ( "(" ~> expr <~ ")" ).*
def member_access     = atomic_expression ~ ( "." ~> identifier).*
def atomic_expression = identifier |
                        "(" ~> expr  <~ ")"
```