# PEG recursive grammar

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, peg

I'm trying to write a Tiger parser. I initially used PyPEG, but due to some difficulties, I went with Arpeggio.

My grammar is really simple.

```
def number(): return _(r'[0-9]+')
def string(): return _(r"\".*?\"")
def id(): return _(r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*')

def literal(): return [number, string]

def simple_var(): return id

def let_in_exp(): return 'let', 'in', Optional(ZeroOrMore(exp)), 'end'

param = [number, string]
params = Optional(param, ZeroOrMore(',', param))

def function_call(): return id, '(', params, ')'

exp = [let_in_exp, simple_var, literal, function_call]

def code(): return OneOrMore(exp), EOF
```

The difficulty resides in the `let-in-exp` expression.
`let in let in let in end end end` is valid Tiger.

However - currently - Arpeggio doesn't recognize the `let-in-exp` as is, but as three `simple-var`. Indeed, going into the ZeroOrMore(exp), it consumes the `end`, and so doesn't find it for the `let-in-exp`.

How can one resolve such problem?

Comment: I think the problem is that 'let', 'in', and 'end' also match as an `id`. I'm not sure how PyPEG let's you define a negative lookahead, but if you can expand on `id` to *not* match the keywords before matching the regexp, then I think your recursion will work.

Comment: I searched in other projects for lookaheads, and finally found `Not()` and `And()`. That solved it. So thanks a lot!

Anyway, isn't there a more idiomatic way to write a PEG grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an Arpeggio solution, but perhaps more idiomatic to your taste?

```
from pyparsing import (CaselessKeyword,Word,nums,QuotedString,alphas,alphanums,
    Forward,Group,Optional,OneOrMore,ZeroOrMore,delimitedList)

LET,IN,END = map(CaselessKeyword, "let in end".split())

number = Word(nums).setName("number")
string = QuotedString('"')
ident = ~(LET | IN | END) + Word(alphas, alphanums+'_')
ident.setName("ident")

literal = number | string

simple_var = ident

exp = Forward().setName("exp")
let_in_exp = Group(LET + IN + ZeroOrMore(exp) + END).setName("let_in_exp")

param = number | string
params = delimitedList(param)
function_call = ident() + '(' + Optional(params) + ')'

exp <<= let_in_exp | simple_var | literal | function_call

code = OneOrMore(exp)

tests = """\
    let in let in let in end end end
    let in let in let in "blah" end end end
    let in let in let in "blah" end 1729 end end
    """
code.runTests(tests)
```

I designed pyparsing to permit combining of expressions using arithmetic operators:

- `+` -> And
- `|` -> Match First
- `^` -> Or (try all, match longest)
- `~` -> Not
- `&` -> Each (same as And, but in any order)
- `*` -> multiple (as in `expr*3` instead of `expr+expr+expr`)

I believe these operators and the plain language class names like `OneOrMore` make these parsers easier to understand, and to maintain over time.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
By more idiomatic, I was thinking about something related to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374121/non-left-recursive-peg-grammar-for-an-expression).

Answer (score 3):

As Paul already noted, you should use `Not` syntactic predicate to avoid matching keywords by `simple_var` rule. Also, I suggest not to wrap `ZeroOrMore` parsing expression in `Optional` as it is already implied.

Solution for Arpeggio is

```
from arpeggio import Not, OneOrMore, ZeroOrMore, Optional, EOF, ParserPython
from arpeggio import RegExMatch as _

keyword = ['let', 'in', 'end']   
def number(): return _(r'[0-9]+')
def string(): return _(r"\".*?\"")
def id(): return _(r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*')

def literal(): return [number, string]
def simple_var(): return Not(keyword), id
def let_in_exp(): return 'let', 'in', ZeroOrMore(exp), 'end'

param = [number, string]
params = Optional(param, ZeroOrMore(',', param))

def function_call(): return id, '(', params, ')'

exp = [let_in_exp, simple_var, literal, function_call]

def code(): return OneOrMore(exp), EOF

parser = ParserPython(code, debug=True)
test = 'let in 42 let in "foo" let in end end end'
parse_tree = parser.parse(test)
```

This will yield the following parse tree

[image]

Comment: That's what I ended up using.
I'll suggest that you add something about lookaheads on the getting started page.
Thanks !